# What is the lift-to-weight ratio during takeoff for an ultralight?

Tags: takeoff, aircraft-physics, ultralight

Lift to weight ratio at cruise is 1:1, what is the average lift to weight ratio during takeoff (rotation) of an ultralight with 2m/s as rate of climb?

Answer (score 1):

Your (lift to weight ratio) load factor is less then 1 during climb.

In a climb or descend only some of the weight is counterbalanced by lift, another part is counterbalanced by thrust. So lift is less then weight in a steady climb. (But Thrust is greater then drag) To calculate the exact Lift to weight ratio we will need more information.